# Odd bugs in terrarium. Harmful?

Tags: species-identification

I noticed these bugs in my terrarium, there is a springtail in the photo for size reference.

I've seen 3 or 4 so far, I'm worried about it out-competing my springtails or possibly being a parasite that will spread to other tanks.  It is shaped like a tick. It's really hard to see but I think it has 6 legs and 2 antennas.

I live in Central Illinois.

I have an African Bullfrog who I occasionally feed live mice, but he is on the other side of the room.

I was thinking that it was probably a mite of some sort. According to an article by the [IDPH, the only pest mite in Illinois would be the Clover Mite](https://dph.illinois.gov/topics-services/environmental-health-protection/structural-pest-control/occasional-invaders.html).  It doesn't look like a Clover Mite, but it does look similar to a predatory mite, like the Amblyseius Cucumeris.

[image]

Comment: Shaped like a tick; it'll be a mite (also in the Acari with ticks). Which mite would take microscopic examination, unless it were the red velvet mite, which are quite obviously red usually.

Comment: Do you have birds or rodents in or nearby the terrarium? Even perhaps outside a nearby window?

Comment: @theforestecologist: I have an African Bullfrog who I occasionally feed live mice, but he is on the other side of the room. To bob1: I was also thinking that it was probably a mite of some sort. According to an [article] (https://dph.illinois.gov/topics-services/environmental-health-protection/structural-pest-control/occasional-invaders.html) by the IDPH, the only pest mite in Illinois would be the Clover Mite. It doesn't look like a Clover Mite, but it does look similar to a predatory mite, like the Amblyseius Cucumeris.

Comment: Welcome to the site; in the SE model, the answer box is only for answers, this isn't a "forum" site where posts make a long chain from oldest-to-newest or vice-versa. The best way to respond to comments asking for clarification is to [edit] your post to include it.

Comment: It's definitely a mite. My questions were trying to determine if it was a bird mite or related. Without better picture and more info, it's unlikely you'll get an accurate and more precise answer